# How use the $lookup in mongodb and nodejs because mine is empty

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am looking for a way to search for data that has a foreign key. But I haven't found it yet. I've been stuck here for a day.
Here is my model

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const UserCGN = mongoose.Schema({
   username: String,
   cours: String
})
module.exports = mongoose.model('UserCGN', UserCGN);

const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Cours = mongoose.Schema({
    name_Cours: String,
    date_Commenc: Date
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('dataCours', Cours);
```

And I have a data in my database like it

dans UserCGN

> username:"njatotianafiononana@gmail.com"
> cours:"Anglais"

et dans le dataCours

> name_Cours:"Anglais"
> date_Commenc:2022-01-12T00:00:00.000+00:00

Et voici mon code pour récuperer

```js
var coursM = await CoursModel.aggregate( [
    {
      $lookup:
        {
          from: "CGNModel",
          localField: "name_Cours",
          foreignField: "cours",
          as: "inventory_docs"
        }
   }
 ] )
console.log("coursM", coursM);
```

In my table inventory_docs is always empty.
Please, help me

Comment: Please mention data that you have in CoursModel and CGNModel.

Answer (score 0):

These two models should be connected. From the snippet you provided, it looks like you forgot to do it, and the model should loke something like this. This way you could do `lookup` with `foreignField: "_id"`

```
const Cours = mongoose.Schema({
    name_Cours: [
      { 
         type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
         ref: 'UserCGN',            
      }
    ],
    date_Commenc: Date
})
```